# cfdocument ignoring the scale directive and autoscaling document

Tags: coldfusion, scale, cfdocument

Environment : ColdFusion 10  on Windows 8.1 and ColdFusion 9 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Using standard versions of IIS.

I am using cfdocument to generate a standard format letter that has variable content.

In amongst the content is a table that has a fixed width (width::700px;)  The document size is A4 with left and right margins of 1.7 cm

I have found that when executing the code on ColdFusion 9, when the width of the table (irrespective of table content) causes the edge of the table to impact the document margin, then cfdocument decides that it ought to auto-scale and it proceeds to reduce the font size of the whole document.

Which would be fine, except that the client insist that the document be produced using a font size of Arial 10 pt.  We don't want autoscaling.

We found that reducing the width of the table did the trick, and stopped ColdFusion 9 from messing with the document scale.  We had to have a good dose of imagination to accomplish this, because the issue did not appear even when we added a border to the table.
I note that we have set `scale="100"` set in the cfdocument directive, but in this case it seems to be ignored, and no error message of any sort.

Now, with ColdFusion 10, behaviour seems to be different.
Having reduced the size of the table as above, running the exact same code and the exact same data, I find that cfdocument has decided to up-size everything from 10pt to 12pt just because it feels like it.

The issue for us is that we are developing on PC that runs ColdFusion 10 to a server that runs ColdFusion 9.
So you can imagine that this means extra development/testing effort.  It is real pain.

I can find no documentation from Adobe that mentions changes to the behaviour of cfdocument between 
ColdFusion 9 and ColdFusion 10.

Is there any way to tell cfdocument to stop messing with the scale of the document and have it stick for ColdFusion 9, 10 (and 11) ?